# Android Studio 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' file not found

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, opencv

I am using Android Studio 2.3 and get fatal error: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' file not found

I saw many similar issues that are not build Android.mk, but my Android.mk should already built.

If change include path of OpenCV.mk in Android.mk it will report file not found error, so I think Android.mk is already included in build process and file path is correct.

If include path is correct, OpenCV.mk should find folder opencv2 but I still get file not found error.

Is there any other way to set include path in Android Studio?

What's wrong in my build script?

native-lib.cpp

```
#include <DetectionBasedTracker.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/contrib/detection_based_tracker.hpp>
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+=$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl
LOCAL_MODULE:= native-lib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a
```

build.gradle

```
android {
          ......
          ......

         sourceSets.main {
              jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
         }

         task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
              commandLine 'F:\\Android_SDK\\ndk-bundle\\ndk-build.cmd',
              '-C', file('src\\main\\jni').absolutePath,
              'NDK_DEBUG=1',
              'V=1'
         }

         tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
         }
}
```

file structure as below

```
app/src/main/jni/Android.mk
app/src/main/jni/Application.mk
app/src/main/jni/native-lib.cpp
app/build.gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import OpenCV Library as a module and  Can you try like this in **Android.mk** file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

 #opencv

OPENCVROOT:= F:/Android/Libs/OpenCV
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := MyOpenCVLibs
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In **build.gradle** under command line you can add like this,

```
commandLine "F:\\Android\\NDK\\android-ndk-r14\\build\\ndk-build.cmd",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
```

Comment: Yes, OpenCVLibrary320 is imported in project_structure->dependencies the scope is compile

I am sorry for the ugly android.mk I provided, after change Android.mk and build.gradle as suggested still not work.

Comment: native-lib.so generate successfully when directly execute ndk-build.cmd with parameters in project folder, but in Android Studio still get  "fatal error: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' file not found"

Comment: After installing Opencv, check you had given installed directory in System's Environment Variable **Path**.

Comment: I downloaded opencv "android pack" from http://opencv.org/releases.html
and unzipped under F:\OpenCV-android-sdk
Should I add F:\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include into System Environment variable path ?

Comment: After added F:\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include to windows->Properties->Advanced system settings->Advanced->Environment Variables->Path, and restart android studio, still not working

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding your explanation.
Where can I get openCV install package for android on windows platform?
After install openCV, should I add the installed directory path to android studio or windows system environment path ?